# Python Print Parts Of Dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, inquirer

I'm writing some python using the module inquirer and it returns the results as a python dictionary, like this:

`{'Apps': ['Notes']}`

I was wondering if would be possible to just get the `'Notes'` bit somehow? The code for the selection thing is below but I don't think it is relevant.

```
import os
import inquirer

def app_menu():
    selections = [inquirer.Checkbox('Apps',
                  message='Please select you app',
                  choices=['Weather', 'Notes', 'Calculator', 'Exit'])]

    app_sel = inquirer.prompt(selections)
    print(app_sel.values())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
print(app_sel['Apps'])
```

Or this, if you're sure that there's only one element in the list:

```
print(app_sel['Apps'][0])
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have result in dict named "result" as below

```
result = {'Apps': ['Notes']}
```

You can directly get it as

```
result['Apps'][0]
```